# python's `with` statement target is unexpectedly None

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager, as-keyword

seems like I do not understand something with---the python `with` statement.

Consider this class:

```
class test(object):
    def __enter__(self): pass
    def __exit__(self, *ignored): pass
```

now, when using it with `with`, like in

```
with test() as michael:
    print repr(michael)
```

I would expect some output like *<test instance at memore blah>*. But I get *None*.

Something wrong here? Any suggestions would help.

(I am using Python 2.6.6.)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to 
[ephement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) for pointing me to the documentation. The `__enter__` method should read

```
    def __enter__(self): return self
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) documentation:

> If a target was included in the `with` statement, the return value from `__enter__()` is assigned to it.

If you `def __enter__(self): return self`, then your expected output is produced.

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__):

> `object.__enter__(self)`
>
> Enter the runtime context related to this object. **The `with` statement will bind this method’s return value to the target(s) specified in the `as` clause of the statement, if any.**

Answer (score -1):

I get the same thing for `repr(michael)`

Try this instead:

```
m.__repr__()
```

I'm not entirely sure, but I think it has something to do with the fact that you haven't defined the `repr` method in your `test` class

Comment: No, `object.__repr__` is used: